# Notify when getting "no signal" on the LG Q6

Tags: notifications, lg, 8.1-oreo, network-signal, alerts

For several days now, the [LG Q6](https://www.gsmarena.com/lg_q6-8756.php) has made me angry when it suddenly stops detecting the SIM card. (once or twice a day)

I don't want to discuss the cause and possible solution. (Restart always helps)

The worst part is that the outage cannot be predicted.

Therefore, I want to ask if there is any way that would alert me to this. Either in the absence of a SIM card or on the loss of connection (of course, when the airplane mode is not activated).

Comment: Hi, take note that questions directly asking for app recommendations are off-topic. Instead, we prefer the asker to just state the underlying problem that they want to solve and not putting any restriction for apps-only. Otherwise, you might be interested in our sister site, [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour) instead.

Comment: @AndrewT. OK, sorry. And is there another way?